# Returning a dataset from Database using testcafe

Tags: database, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I am new to testcafe. Here is what I am struggling with:

Say I am entering a value in User Interface using test cafe tool- This part I am able to do.
Next, say I want to query and hit the database to see if the data are successfully updated- This part I am able to write the function in JavaScript. While running the test cafe testing scripts how do I include this JavaScript function in my test script and run these?

I want to call this function in my testcafe test script.

```
Function Cl(){
    Var dbConn= new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
    var request = new sql.Request(dbConn);
    request.query( select TOP 5 from test)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

TestCafe test files are regular Node.js script files. You can copy your function and paste it in a test code directly. Or you can create a separate `.js` file or package and use the `require` function or the ES6 `import` statement to import your function from it.